# Create a CE button in a calculator that delete the text in text box by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a C button that can return all the number back to 0 but i want to ask how to make a CE button for a calculator that could delete the last text. For example I clicked "3" and then "2". When i click CE button it could remove "2" and click again it remove "3" and return it to "0"

Answer (score 0):

below will be help you.

```
$("#clearEnd").click(function() {
    if($display.val().length > 1){
        $display.val($display.val().substring(0,$display.val().length-1));
        // ex) 123->12, 1000->100
    }else{
        // this means click clear[C] button
        $("#clear").trigger("click");
        // ex) 1->0, 2->, 0->0
    }
});
```

Comment: That work for me but what if i deleted the last digit and it return back to 0?